# Google-cast to Android TV emulator

Tags: android-emulator, chromecast, android-tv

I was wondering if I can use the Android TV emulator (available from Android SDK) as a Chromecast emulator.

Android TV devices (like the Nexus Player) are Google Cast targets. I was assuming that the Android TV emulator is Google Cast enabled, but no app can find it on the network (even Chrome on the host that runs the emulator).

So either it's not enabled in the Android TV emulator, or I have to set up some king of port forwarding between the host and the emulator.

Which is it?

Comment: /me wondering if this question belongs in SO instead.